# Getting status of task from Django Background Tasks

Tags: django

I am working with Django and i want to start some background tasks. I found the library "Django Background Tasks". It has almost everything I need but I can not find how to get the status of the task (pending/running/completed) anywhere in the documentation (http://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It would be very helpful for me if someone could tell me how to get the status of the task.

Answer (score 4):

The tasks are inserted in the DB table `background_task` and after it completes, the task is moved from `background_task` table to `background_task_completedtask` table. You can use this information to create a view to get the status of all / particular tasks.

**Example**:

```
from background_task.models import Task
from background_task.models_completed import CompletedTask
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

def get_status(request):
    now = timezone.now()

    # pending tasks will have `run_at` column greater than current time.
    # Similar for running tasks, it shall be
    # greater than or equal to `locked_at` column.
    # Running tasks won't work with SQLite DB,
    # because of concurrency issues in SQLite.
    pending_tasks_qs = Task.objects.filter(run_at__gt=now)
    running_tasks_qs = Task.objects.filter(locked_at__gte=now)

    # Completed tasks goes in `CompletedTask` model.
    # I have picked all, you can choose to filter based on what you want.
    completed_tasks_qs = CompletedTask.objects.all()

    # main logic here to return this as a response.

    # just for test
    print (pending_tasks_qs, running_tasks_qs, completed_tasks_qs)
    return HttpResponse("ok")
```

Finally, register this view in urlpatterns and check the status.